# HttpClient: limit response (downloaded file) size while using HttpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I am looking for a way to police the size of a downloaded file, while using the following code:

```
    var client = new HttpClient();

    HttpResponseMessage resp = await client.GetAsync(mediaUri, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);

    using (var fileStream = File.Create(outputPath))
    {
        using (var httpStream = await resp.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
        {
            httpStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
            fileStream.Flush();
        }
    }
```

How do I prevent download of files larger than predefined size?

**Edit:**

Before the answers below came in, I resorted to replacing `CopyTo` with this. I am putting it here to maybe weight against the `ProgressMessageHandler` from the answers below:

```
            using (var fileStream = File.Create(outputPath))
            {
                using (var httpStream = await resp.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
                {
                    // instead of httpStream.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[65536];
                    while (true)
                    {
                        int read = await httpStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, ct);
                        if (read <= 0)
                            break;

                        // do the policing here

                        await fileStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, read);
                    }
                    fileStream.Flush();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Yes, your solution should work fine.  If you wrap it in a ReadAs extension method you can make it nice and neat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Richard's answer doesn't help because the content is chunked then you should look into the `ProgressMessageHandler` that is part of the WebAPI.Client nuget that receives events periodically and allows you to monitor the bytes transferred.  Using this event handler you could cancel the operation if the bytes transferred exceeds a certain amount.

Answer (score 3):

Try checking [the `resp.Content.Headers.ContentLength` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.headers.httpcontentheaders.contentlength%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which should contain the size of the file in bytes.

Comment: Assuming the content isn't chunked.

Comment: I have had mixed success with this as it appeared that not all servers included it in the response. Speaking few years ago, but still...

Comment: @G.Stoynev: I haven't tried it, but I've seen a suggestion that the `HttpClient` buffers the response, and should return the content length correctly even if the server didn't send it. http://forums.asp.net/t/1813991.aspx

Comment: I believe I specifically instruct against buffering with `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead`

Comment: @G.Stoynev Correct.  Kinda pointless to download all the content into a buffer and then say, no you can't download the content!